# Is it possible to create issue in JIRA 4.4 via REST API?

Tags: jira

I'm trying to understand is it possible to create issue in JIRA 4.4 via REST API.
i'm start local JIRA 4.4 server, and trying to create issue, by sending json via rest client **Link:http://localhost:9090/rest/api/2/issue/** but it response with next data

```
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-AREQUESTID: 972x1063x1
X-ASESSIONID: 1qhj5t4
X-Seraph-LoginReason: OK
X-AUSERNAME: admin
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1006
Date: Thu, 03 May 2012 12:12:32 GMT
```

and use next json

```
{
    "fields": {
       "project":
       { 
          "key": "TEST"
       },
       "summary": "REST ye merry gentlemen.",
       "description": "Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API",
       "issuetype": {
          "name": "Bug"
       }}}
```

i do this according to JIRA [doc](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Example+-+Create+Issue).
i so confused what i doing wrong, 
Maybe anyone familiar with this Error?

Comment: i upgrade to JIRA v5.0.3 and solve the problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem solved. Main reason why it happend that json have some syntax errors.